# nth term remainder and comparison test

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given ${\{a_n}\}$ and ${\{b_n}\}$ such that $0\le{a_n}\le{b_n}$:

if $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}b_n$ converges than $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n$ does,

if $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}a_n$ diverges positively than $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}b_n$ does too.

But I don't get why, given $r_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}a_k$ and $R_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{+\infty}b_k$ it is (eventually) $r_n\le R_n$

Can you help me with a demonstration and possibly a visual representation? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean with eventually?

Comment: Why are you interested in $r_n,R_n$? They aren't required for the usual proof...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine which series comparison test to use?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/172478/how-can-i-determine-which-series-comparison-test-to-use)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summing a finite number of inequalities $a_k\le b_k$:
$$\sum_{k=n+1}^m a_k\le\sum_{k=n+1}^m b_k.$$
And now, take $\lim_{m\to\infty}$